# problema al intentar usar serialport en electron

Tags: nodejs, electron

Buenas... instale serialport con `npm install --save serialport` y al hacer `let serialport = require('serialport');` y tratar de correr la aplicación me salta el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esto en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pd: No supe como buscar el problema en google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para electron existe browser-serialport. que es lo mismo que serialport, pero para aplicaciones de navegadores.

https://github.com/garrows/browser-serialport

```
npm uninstall --save serialport
npm install --save browser-serialport
```